# #1054 - Unknown column 'de15a674d1252f6565a65756ebfa97e8e1e58c9c' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

i have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ud_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

and mycatch table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mycatch` (
  `catch_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catch_name` text NOT NULL,
  `catch_details` text NOT NULL,
  `longitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `image` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`catch_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE `mycatch`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `mycatch_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

i want to retrieve data from both the tables. i.e

```
SELECT longitude,latitude
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN mycatch m ON u.user_id = m.user_id
WHERE u.ud_id =de15a674d1252f6565a65756ebfa97e8e1e58c9c
AND m.catch_id >7
```

but this give me error `#1054 - Unknown column 'de15a674d1252f6565a65756ebfa97e8e1e58c9c' in 'where clause'` 

but when i change u.ud_id=123456789 then it works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need single quotes around the u.ud_id

```
SELECT longitude,latitude
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN mycatch m ON u.user_id = m.user_id
WHERE u.ud_id = 'de15a674d1252f6565a65756ebfa97e8e1e58c9c'
AND m.catch_id >7
```

Comment: how can i retrieve all the fields from mycatch table using the same query

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your value in quotes:

```
... WHERE u.ud_id='de15a674d1252f6565a65756ebfa97e8e1e58c9c' ...
```